# vue datepicker returns "1969" value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, datepicker, vue-component

I have implemented the vue datepicker component as shown in the link below:
https://github.com/ReproNim/reproschema-ui/blob/master/src/components/Inputs/YearInput/YearInput.vue

when this component is answered and i move to a different page and revisit this page where the datepicker is, the value gets modified to "1969".
in the mounted method (line 53 in above link), i check for any initialized value. if present, it is assigned to data "input". i checked the init value and it is correct (it has the previously answered value) but on screen the component shows "1969".

can someone help as to why this happens?

Comment: That's probably the default (null) date. The unix epoch date is Jan 1, 1970 (GMT). In the USA, that would be Dec 31 1969.

Comment: yes. how can i get my expected output instead of default? and why does the default appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to solve this question!

when the answered value is "year", eg. 1990, in the mounted lifecycle hook, before assigning it to the data variable, I need to convert the 'year' value to a date object.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks correct for the most part.

Perhaps the input value is not formatted correcty so the default of 'epoch' is used.

Or your typos are causing the problem...

`lang=selected_language` and `:initialView=inputType` and `:minimumView=inputType`

```
    <datepicker placeholder="Select Date" v-model="input" :lang='selected_language'
                :disabledDates="dateParam.disabledDates" :format="customFormatter"
                :minimumView='inputType' :maximumView="'year'" :initialView='inputType'
                ></datepicker>
```

Comment: sorry, what did you mean by typos are causing the problem? I didn't understand..
in my code, selected_language = 'en', inputType= 'year'. so the input value is also an year, eg. 1980

Comment: you need quotes when using v-bind or the `:` character

Comment: i made the above changes which you mentioned but still doesn't work. can't understand what is wrong..

Comment: First step is to put a value directly in value='your-value'. if that is correct in display, then put a breakpoint into the assignment of your bound value. so replace v-model with just the one-way value assignment.